# Accessing a protected .net API with a token from IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have working prototype Visual Studio Solution using IdentityServer4 which has:

- IdentityServer (asp.net core mvc)
- API project (asp.net core mvc)
- Web Client 1 (MVC/Angular) (Username/password protected admin portal) talking to API
- Web Client 2 (MVC) (Public facing website, no login)

I have the login working and basic test of Web Client 1 working talking to API.

My question is best described using an example:
Suppose I have a method in my API protected with the [Authorize] attribute for GetCourses (protected with authorize so its not accessible by anybody if they know the URL).   This currently work because my test is logging in with a user on web client 1 (which would be used to edit courses eventually).

But on my Public facing website I want to be able to call GetCourses with ClientCredentials in IdentityServer so I can display a list of courses on the website. I expect I'm going about this the wrong way so if anyone can provide any pointers it would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use cookie authentication for Web Client 1:

```
  // for Web Client 1  Scheme = Cookies
  app.UseCookieAuthentication();

  // for Web Client 2 Scheme = Bearer
  app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
  {
       ...
  });
```

You just need to use `ActiveAuthenticationSchemes` like below:

```
 [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Cookies, Bearer")]
 public IActionResult GetCourses(){ ... }
```

For more info see https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.html

Comment: Ah that sounds like what i'm looking for, will research that further, thanks